# How to use BeginSaveChanges and EndSaveChanges for Async call method in OData

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have written the below code to update the data but need to use the async call to save changes for Odata.

```
 var result = context.Batch.Where(i => i.Item_No ==   "235").First();

            result.ItemQty = 10;
            context.UpdateObject(result);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Please help me here to use the BeginSaveChanges and EndSaveChanges to do the async call

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to make the function asynchronous, then you should modify the code as follows:

```
public async Task Save(){    
    var result = await context.Batch.Where(i => i.Item_No == "235").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if(result != null)
    {
        result.ItemQty = 10;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: SaveChangesAsync and FirstOrDefaultAsync are not coming xamarin project. only available options are BeginSavechnages and EndSavechanges